# How to print from a file transaction type and amount involved , seperated by comma or single space?

Tags: c

every transaction is in a new line and the action (withdraw or debit) is seperated by commas or single spaces. Can anyone help me out here? i also need to store the data into an array and determine how many transactions are there the information is in text file like this, w represents withdraw and d represents deposit, i need to get the data into an array fromthe file, (transactions1 and transaction2 are on new lines) assume they are three transactions two of which are show below

transaction1, w 3000 transaction2, d 4000
this is the code that i produced but teh program crashes and nothing gets printed
i tried it with out the commas and just single spaces but stil doesnt work

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main()
{//open main
    int i;
    char array1[3];//array to store type of transaction, 'w' or'd' depending on    withdraw or deposit
    int array2[3];//array to store amount involved in transaction
    FILE *fptr = fopen("transactions.txt", "r");
    if((fptr = fopen("transactions.txt", "r"))==NULL)
    printf("error in opening file");
    for (i = 0; i<3 ; i++)
    {
      fscanf(fptr,"%s");
      fscanf(fptr, "%c", &array1[i]);
      fscanf(fptr, "%d", &array2[i]);
    }
//checking whether the values and type of transaction successfully stored in       respective arrays
    for (i= 0; i<3; i++)
    {
       printf("%c", array1[i]);
       printf("%d", array2[i]);
    }
    return 0;

}//close main
```

Comment: `fscanf(fptr,"%*[^,],");` or `fscanf(fptr,"%[^,],", dummy);`

Answer (score 1):

As [BLUEPIXY](https://stackoverflow.com/users/971127/bluepixy) mentioned, you need to use `fscanf(fptr,"%*[^,],");` instead of `fscanf(fptr,"%s");` to read and discard everything upto the first `','`, and then you can read one character and one integer from the file.

And also, you have to return if the file is not open properly.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main()
{//open main
    int i;
    char array1[3];//array to store type of transaction, 'w' or'd' depending on    withdraw or deposit
    int array2[3];//array to store amount involved in transaction
    FILE *fptr;
    if((fptr = fopen("transactions.txt", "r"))==NULL)
    {
      printf("error in opening file");
      return 0;
    }
    for (i = 0; i<3 ; i++)
    {
      fscanf(fptr,"%*[^,],");
      fscanf(fptr, " %c", &array1[i]);
      fscanf(fptr, "%d", &array2[i]);
    }
//checking whether the values and type of transaction successfully stored in       respective arrays
    for (i= 0; i<3; i++)
    {
       printf("%c", array1[i]);
       printf(" %d", array2[i]);
    }
    return 0;

}//close main
```

I have used the following file content:

> transaction1, w 4000
>  transaction2, d 3000
>  transaction3, d 5000

Comment: it still prints garbage even after i have used fscanf(fptr,"%*[^,],");

Comment: @user3051896, please see my updated answer. You need to add a space before `%c` to omit the space after comma.

Answer (score 0):

please try with below, i not tested

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main()
{
int i;
char array1[3];
int array2[3];
FILE *fptr = fopen("transactions.txt", "r");
if(fptr == NULL)
{
    printf("error in opening file");
    return -1;
}
for (i = 0; i<3 ; i++)
{
  fscanf(fptr, "%c %d", &array1[i], &array2[i]);
}
for (i= 0; i<3; i++)
{
   printf("%c %d\n", array1[i], array2[i]);
}
fclose(fptr);
return 0;

}//close main
```